# R spplot() how to change the unit type of the scale bar

Tags: r, dictionary, r-sp

I have drawn a basic map using spplot()(package sp)

The scale bar legend is in decimal places between 0 and 1 but I actually want this to show percentages.

If I use the Plot() function for a simple graph, i can change the scale by adding them manually.
Is there an equivalent way to do this in spplot where I can manually define the unit type?

Example:

```
library(sp)
library(lattice)
trellis.par.set(sp.theme()) # sets bpy.colors() ramp
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
spplot(meuse, "ffreq")
```

the plot shows 1,2,3 as the legend. What if hypothetically I wanted to show this as $1, $2, $3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `legendEntries` argument ([showcased here](http://rspatial.r-forge.r-project.org/gallery/#fig02.R)) lets you supply a character vector of text labels to an `spplot()` legend. Use it like this:

```
spplot(meuse, "ffreq", legendEntries = paste0("$", levels(meuse$ffreq)))
```

[image]

Comment: How to apply this to an example where my scale is determined from continuous data, rather than discrete?

Comment: I managed to do it by using the labels argument within spplot. i.e. legend_label_at = seq(0,max(ceiling(x$legend$right$args$key$at*10)/10),0.1)
legend_label = paste0(legend_label_at * 100,"%")
  labels=list( 
                    at=legend_label_at,
                    labels=legend_label )

Comment: @shecode Hmm. Glad you found a solution, although the labels argument doesn't do anything for me here. I was also stumped in my attempts to make this modification via the `key=` and `auto.key=` arguments. (The latter is the one that seems like it **should** work.) For the record, here are the two things that almost-but-don't-quite work: (1) `spplot(meuse, "ffreq", simpleKey=list(text=LETTERS[1:3]))`; (2) `spplot(meuse, "ffreq", auto.key=list(text=list(LETTERS[1:3])))`

Comment: your solution works for a discrete scale. I did not supply continuous data (which my real dataset is) so i do not blame you for not making it work

Comment: @shecode -- Digging a bit further into the code, I found a much more elegant solution, now edited into my answer. It works equally well for continuous variables, as you can see by trying `spplot(meuse, "zinc", legendEntries = LETTERS[1:5])`. (For the record, I discovered `legendEntries` by having a look first in `getMethod("spplot", "SpatialPointsDataFrame")` and then in `sp:::fill.call.groups`

Answer (score 1):

If you plot a factor, simply changing the labels of the factor may be easier:

```
levels(meuse$ffreq) = c("a", "b", "c")
spplot(meuse, "ffreq")
```

`legendEntries` is documented, but is not a named argument of `spplot`, so lacks in the arguments list. The `spplot` method for `SpatialPointsDataFrame` objects has a `colorkey` argument to plot continuous color keys; upcoming sp 1.0-18 will allow a list argument for it to get the control of the same argument in `lattice::levelplot`

Answer (score 0):

The help page for sp::spplot says this is done using lattice functions and further indicated that one can pass arguments to the `scale` parameters in the same manner as in xyplot. This, however, not likely to affect a legend, but would rather change the annotation of the x and y axes. When I run the first example in the help page I get a scale.bar that goes from 0 to 500 with only those two values as labels. Looking at the code that is used one can deduce that the 'scale.bar' is being constructed with arguments passed to `sp.layout`, in this case `list(l2,l3,l4,l5)`. After a couple a deadend attempts, I came up with this suggestion for how to use the lattice `simpleKey` function to deliver your legend modification and to make the scale bar as in the first example:

```
library(sp); library(lattice)
l2 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), offset = c(181300,329800), 
    scale = 400)
l3 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), offset = c(180500,329800), 
    scale = 500, fill=c("transparent","black"))
l4 = list("sp.text", c(180500,329900), "0")
l5 = list("sp.text", c(181000,329900), "500 m")

spplot(meuse, c("ffreq"), sp.layout=list(l2,l3,l4,l5) 
              ,key=simpleKey( text=paste0("$", 1:3) ) )
```

Note: since `spplot` is an S4 function, this is how you can get to the code:

```
showMethods(spplot, class="SpatialPointsDataFrame", includeDefs=TRUE)
```